# How can I get a legend in my plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial

How can I get a legend from the `Elev_Avg` component of `polydatx`?

I tried using `ax.legend()`, but I got this error:

`No handles with labels found to put in legend.`

Plot

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 8))
polydatx.plot(ax = ax, column = 'Elev_Avg', cmap='OrRd', scheme='quantiles', label='elev')
segdatx.plot(ax = ax)
ax.grid(False)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the xlabel and ylabel first, then set the legend?

Comment: @Arief I don't get it. Why would x/y label affect the legend? I did try `ax.set_xlabel('Long')`, but the error persists.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I relied on precision, considering legend, and axis labels are not remotely the same thing. And it wasn't incomplete code, considering I didn't originally have `label` inside polydatx. However, adding that didn't have an impact. I'll ignore your last sentence - condescending and useless.

Comment: A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful here

Comment: I'm sorry you did not understand my joke. So let me simply cite from the reasons to close a question: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: I don't think it was a joke.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the computer what to put in the legend.  Then you will get it :)

For example, if what you are plotting are two columns ['s1', 's2'] from a pandas dataframe df, then this is what you would do to get the plot and legend:

```
ax.plot(df.loc[:,['s1', 's2']], marker='o')
ax.legend(['s1', 's2'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

According matplotlib document ([matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html))
 the handles is optional, but for some reason most people get that error message. What I did was

handles, labels = ax.get_leggend_handles_labels()

ax.legend(handles, labels). It seems to work for me.